# How to sum percentages in excel, so that they increase as well? Not only to sum up

Tags: excel, percentage

How would one sum up percentages (in Excel), but that they increase as they go?

For instance, I have a table of percentage increase:

[image: table example]

So 1D column should not be a 10% increase in the TOTAL down, but more.
It should be around 12% increase (by my estimate).

Example:

```
 5% > X + 5%
 3% > 105% + 3% (3% out of a now new number which is 105% and not the initial 100%)
 ....
```

So I want to see the increases as they are shown in the table: 5%, 3%, 2%

But the sum should reflect the additions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FVSCHEDULE` function to calculate growing percentage:

```
=FVSCHEDULE(100;A2:A12)/100-1
```

[image]